# Is there something wrong with my query? (DATEDIFF)

Tags: sql

This query is supposed to fetch the students data which is created in a specific day. However if I enter 15 for @NumberOfDays, it returns 15 days and 14 days data and If I enter 20, this time it brings 19 and 20 days data. Can someone help me out with my query please? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT TOP 10 S.Id, S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateCreated
FROM STUDENT S WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, CAST(S.DateCreated AS date), CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) = @NumberOfDays
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that - can you post some examples of DateCreated - I notice you are casting it to a date which suggests it isn't already a date... You also don't need to cast GetDate to a date - it already returns a date

Comment: Do you get all records created on 14th, resp. 19th day, or just a part of them? I'm thinking it might be some sort of timezone issue.

Comment: the reason I cast the value is I only want to compare day, month and year. if I cast it, it basically deletes the time part of date time value.

Comment: `2012-05-25 12:59:09.700
2012-05-27 22:11:11.813
2012-05-28 17:14:23.940
2012-05-31 17:00:45.047
2012-05-25 19:33:13.943
2012-05-27 16:30:08.387
2012-05-08 16:52:34.067
2012-05-09 12:43:37.810
2012-05-13 15:53:55.107
2012-05-13 15:54:01.577`

Comment: r u comparing 14th and 15th day of the current month?

Comment: What do you mean you are getting "15 and 14 days of data"?  By removing the time component, you will be getting differences from just over 14 days (11:59 p.m. on create day to 12:01 a.m. on getdate()) to just under 16 days (12:01 a.m. on create day to 11:59 p.m. on getdate).

Comment: [Your query works for me.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77a00/5)

Comment: datediff('day', etc) isn't going to care about times, so it makes no difference whether you cast to date or not. As it stands, if you pass 14 in, then it will return all records that have a DateCreated any time on 12th June (currently 26th June).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With this query, it finally works!**

```
SELECT TOP 10 S.Id, S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateCreated
FROM STUDENT S WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE CAST(S.DateCreated AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -@NumberOfDays, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: thanks for everyone who tried their best to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 S.Id, S.Name, S.Surname, S.DateCreated
FROM STUDENT S WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, CAST(S.DateCreated AS date), CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) 
Between @NumberOfDays-1 and @NumberOfDays
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't vote down your answer. what you wrote guarantees the return of 13 days, 14 and 15 if I enter 15 for NumberOfDays

Comment: r u comparing 14th and 15th day of the current month?

Comment: I think the OP's issue is this: they enter `15` expecting dates that are 15 days apart from today, but they get dates that are 15 *and 14* days apart. Your suggestion seems to make things worse by *also* introducing days that are 13 days apart from today. (And I didn't downvote your answer either.)